# UPDATE нескольких строк одного поля - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица **table** в БД, где два поля у них - две записи:

```
   id  field1 field2
     1    asc     1
     2    desc    0
```

имеется HTML тег select с выбором двух полей:

```
<select name="filter">
    <option value="asc">возрастание</option>
    <option value="desc">уменьшение</option>
    </select>
```

Как у **field2** сделать **UPDATE**, чтобы постоянно были 0 и 1 в зависимости от выбора **select** на форме? Например, если выбран "возрастание", то в БД asc = 1, desc = 0 и наоборот

Comment: Напишите запрос, выполните его, в чем проблема?

Comment: в описании поста описал в чем проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно в таблицу добавить тригеры на обновление и инсерт

```
CREATE  TRIGGER `tr_upd` BEFORE UPDATE ON `table` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
 IF( NEW.field1 == 'asc') THEN
 SET NEW.field2 = 1;
 ELSE
 SET NEW.field2 = 0;
 END IF;
 END;
```

Comment: тригеры нужно отдельно добавлять, или в данном запросе они автоматически добавятся?

Comment: это в самой таблице а дальше второе поле будет обновляться само

Answer (score 0):

Тут можно использовать обычный SQL-запрос, советую пользоваться MySQLi-драйвером, читайте док-ию. сам запрос и псевдо-код:

```html
если выбран OPTION1 (Возрастание):
UPDATE `table` SET asc = 1, desc = 0;
если выбран OPTION2 (Убывание):
UPDATE `table` SET asc = 0, desc = 1;
```

Comment: это нужно оператором if, а если будет 10 параметров для фильтра, это 10 раз if нужно будет?

Comment: Да, 10 раз if, либо сделать штуку такую: UPDATE всех полей на 0, после в запрос в конец добавить конструкцию вида VALUE . ' = 1';

Comment: А можно switch-case перебор сделать. 
Либо примудрить сюда массив и перебирать foreach ища совпадения. Вариантов масса.

Comment: Ну, switch-вариант тоже вариант, но видишь, он кажись не хочет писать видимо кучу sql-запросов под каждый кейс

Comment: Можно сделать запрос в БД, получить field1 в виде массива, получить значение из `select` , потом циклом перебрать массив на совпадение. В случае совпадения делать `UPDATE` в базу, в этот момент у тебя будут все данные для формирования "типового" `UPDATE`, в который ты подставишь значения из массива и `select`.  Хреново что будет два запроса в БД, вместо одного и дольше перебор. Зато меньше кода.

Comment: Николай Габараев, на самом деле полей больше чем 2, мне нужно при выборе одного поля, сделать его 1, все остальные должны быть 0, через кучу if как автор ответа порекомендовал сделал, но хотелось бы правильно реализовать

Comment: Я ответил, как вам надо сделать.Через массивы, циклы, и поиск соответсвий.

Comment: UPDATE всех полей на 0, после в запрос в конец добавить конструкцию вида VALUE . ' = 1';

Comment: Вот вам еще один способ который я написал